# Skype API Wrapper with WIndows 8 Store App

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, skype

I need to integrate Skype deep into one of my Windows 8 Store application for Windows 8 Pro. We need to show the online status of the user and trace if the call was placed successfully.

We have tried to use Skype4COM but apparently, Win8 Store Apps can only access limited set of COM components.

I am not open to use to use Skype URIs as i would require to trace the status of the call also.

Any pointers or any help would be awesome!!!

Answer (score 2):

At this time, the Skype API is not a Windows Runtime Component so it can't be used in a Windows Store app. Even though COM objects are similar, they don't work in Windows Store apps because they have a different interface, security model, etc.

Right now, Skype URIs are your only option for a Windows Store app. You can find more information on Skype URIs and Windows Store apps @ http://dev.skype.com/skype-uri/skype-uri-tutorial-win8.